# Django model instance with nested field filter

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I have these two models:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    pass

class Result(models.Model)
    task = models.ForeignKey('tasks.Task', related_name='results')
    enabled = models.BooleanField('enabled', default=False)
```

And I want to get task with filtered results for my temporary calculations:

```
task = Task.objects.first()
results = task.results.filter(enabled=True)
task.results.set(results)
```

This is the working code, but task results will be rewritten after the first usage. How to get the new task with filtered results without task.results rewriting? I need to keep the changed task instance in memory only.

---

My final point is to pass the task to the serializer. But it seems to me the serializer **must serialize** and **not to filter** something. Because the context of filtering may be different in other submodules.

```
class ResultSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin, ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Result


class TaskResultsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    results = ResultSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

Comment: What you mean by *broken* ?\

Comment: @JPG because results will be replaced by .set(). I want to have new task with filtered results in memory only.

Comment: Ok. I've replaced broken/destroyed to rewrite. Hope it's much clear.

Comment: I see - so the problem is that you can't just edit it in memory and then have your downstream serializer use the edited version, because it's a reverse foreign key manager? What serializer are you using? You might need to tweak it.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Set is used for replacing related objects. You getting results and then reset them. I'm not sure why? Maybe you are trying to do the update?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update

Comment: No, I want to pass this task to serializer (serializer is with results)

Answer (score 1):

It looks from your choice of serializer class like you're using the Django REST framework for serialization. If that's correct, I would handle this by declaring a callable on the `Task` model that returns the results you want to include, and then explicitly specifying a serializer field for that callable. EG:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    def enabled_results(self):
        return self.results.filter(enabled=True)

class TaskResultsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    results = ResultSerializer(source='enabled_results', many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

This is untested, but it looks like it should work.